# How to use waitMe loader with AngularJs app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using waitMe (http://vadimsva.github.io/waitMe/) loading for my angular js application. Here's how I have added it into my project.

```
<link href="lib/css/waitMe.css" rel="stylesheet"> <script src="lib/js/waitMe.js"></script>
```

And here the javascript code for the waiting message.

```
$('#login-box-body').waitMe({
            effect: 'bounce',
            text: '',
            bg: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
            color: '#000',
            maxSize: '',
            waitTime: -1,
            source: 'img.svg',
            textPos: 'vertical',
            fontSize: '',
            onClose: function (el) {
            }
        });
```

And this is the div which i have used in the javascript message generator.

```
<div class="login-box-body">

    <div class="wrapper">
        <form class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign In</h2>
            <div style="text-align: center">
```

But when I press the button, nothing appears, no error message too. What's the reason for this ? Am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here `$('#login-box-body').waitMe({`. You can fix it in below two ways:

1. Change `#login-box-body` to `.login-box-body` in JavaScript

JavaScript:

```
$('.login-box-body').waitMe({
            effect: 'bounce',
            text: '',
            bg: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
            color: '#000',
            maxSize: '',
            waitTime: -1,
            source: 'img.svg',
            textPos: 'vertical',
            fontSize: '',
            onClose: function (el) {
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="login-box-body">

    <div class="wrapper">
        <form class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign In</h2>
            <div style="text-align: center">
```

2. Change `<div class="login-box-body">` to `<div id="login-box-body">`

JavaScript:

```
$('#login-box-body').waitMe({
                effect: 'bounce',
                text: '',
                bg: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
                color: '#000',
                maxSize: '',
                waitTime: -1,
                source: 'img.svg',
                textPos: 'vertical',
                fontSize: '',
                onClose: function (el) {
                }
            });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="login-box-body">

    <div class="wrapper">
        <form class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign In</h2>
            <div style="text-align: center">
```

Comment: @Chanaka De Silva, did you check my answer?